# Silverlight game development learning links

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight 5 beta is coming very soon. I want to explore Silverlight Game development skills. Could you please suggest some good sites where I can learn Silverlight game development easily. I Googled and Binged for the same but did not get good results.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have anything for SL 5, but Mike Snow's blog has many game programming tips: http://www.michaelsnow.com/

The site used to be here: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/default.aspx

For example, here's a Rendering event for your main game loop: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/09/29/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-50-main-game-loop-revisited.aspx